# При вызове Client.Dispose() открывается окно в браузере (в Chrome)

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Есть функция, которая скачивает html код сайта

```
    public string OriginalHtml(string url) {
        WebBrowser Client = new WebBrowser();
        Client.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        Client.Navigate(url);

        while (Client.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        string Result = Client.DocumentText;
        //Если сюда вставить месседжбокс, то проблема исчезает, но программа работает в фоне и отвлекаться на постоянное нажатие кнопочки никакого желания нет
        Client.Dispose();

        return Result;
    }
```

Опять же, если не использовать Dispose() все работает нормально, но очень большие утечки в памяти, что является недопустимым.

url подается корректный, есть только одно но, она перенаправляет на другой адрес.

Помогите пожалуйста, борюсь с этим багом уже более недели.

Comment: если нужно просто загрузить HTML, зачем WebBrowser? Используйте WebCilent

Comment: сайт блокирует такие подключения

Comment: Надо разбираться по какому признаку блокирует. Если по User-Agent, то его можно поменять.

Comment: А используя webbrowser решить проблему не получится ?

Comment: Сайт вроде просто блокирует слишком частые подключения через WebClient с одного ip

Comment: В запросах WebClient нет большой надписи "Я WebClient!!!!11". Нужно понять, как именно сайт определяет, что запрос послан автоматикой вместо реального браузера, и подменить нужные HTTP-заголовки. Что касается,  "При вызове Dispose() открывается окно в браузере" - не встречался с такой проблемой. Если MessageBox помогает, то может что-то вроде Thread.Sleep(1000) тоже поможет